# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cot^{-1}u_n$ where $u_1=1$, $u_2=2$ and $u_{n+1}=3u_n-u_{n-1}$

Tags: limits, summation

> for sequence $u_n$ such that $u_1=1$, $u_2=2$, and $u_{n+1}=3u_n-u_{n-1}$,
> ${{v}_{n}}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\cot ^{-1}{{u}_{k}}}$ . Find  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}v_n$

I founnd $u_n=\sqrt{5}\cdot\left({{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}^{2n-1}}+{{\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)}^{2n-1}}\right)$
but don't know

Comment: Where is this problem from? (Please put this information into the question body.)

Answer (score 3):

Let $u_0=1$, so that the recurrence $u_{n+1}=3u_n-u_{n-1}$ also holds at $n=1$.

Then we have $u_n^2-3u_n u_{n-1}+u_{n-1}^2=-1$ (to prove, use induction on $n$).

Now let $a_n=\cot^{-1}(u_n-u_{n-1})$. Then, using $\cot(x-y)=\frac{\cot x\cot y+1}{\cot y-\cot x}$, $$\cot(a_n-a_{n+1})=\frac{(u_n-u_{n-1})(u_{n+1}-u_n)+1}{(u_{n+1}-u_n)-(u_n-u_{n-1})}=\frac{(u_n-u_{n-1})(2u_n-u_{n-1})+1}{u_n}=u_n.$$

Hence $a_n-a_{n+1}=\cot^{-1}u_n$ and, finally, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cot^{-1}u_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n-a_{n+1})=a_1=\frac\pi2.$$